# retrieving text from a group of textareas

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write out the text from a group of textareas all with the same name.

For some reason, it's not working.

Here are my text areas:

```
<textarea name="tbmcqAnswer"></textarea> 
<textarea name="tbmcqAnswer"></textarea>
<textarea name="tbmcqAnswer"></textarea>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
var answers;
$(function() {
     $('textarea[name="tbmcqAnswer"]').map(function () {
         answers = "<h3>" + this.value + "</h3>"
     })
})
div.html(answers);
```

Comment: Why do your textareas have the same name??

Comment: because I'm trying to group them all so I can loop through them

Comment: Use class instead, then @999cm999

Comment: use class and $.each instead of map()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -  (*You will get array of all values*)

```
var answers;
$(function () {
    answers = $('textarea[name="tbmcqAnswer"]').map(function () {
        return "<h3>" + this.value + "</h3>";
    }).get();
    $('div').html(answers.join(''));
});
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/wdJka/3/

Comment: Won't you have to loop through `answers` and append? Or will this just append them all at once?

Comment: I know `.map()` will do the looping and create the array `answers`. I was asking about the `div.html(answers)`.

Comment: Ahh got it. Thx. +1 on fixing OP `.map()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this also

Give class as

```
<textarea class="tbmcqAnswer"></textarea> 
<textarea class="tbmcqAnswer"></textarea>
<textarea class="tbmcqAnswer"></textarea>
```

And js goes like this :

```
var answers=[];
$(".tbmcqAnswer").each(function(){
 answers.push(this.value);
});

 $("div").html(answers.join(","));
```

for your reference - http://jsfiddle.net/QphrP/
Above will give you the desired results and better then name and .map()